# Updating a column using VBA code removes the Format of the column

Tags: excel, vba

My excel contains two buttons. One called "Highlight" for highlighting particular columns another called "Recalculate" for updating the column after calculation. Lets say I clicked "Highlight" button, and the column B highlights in yellow color. Now when I click "Recalculate" button, it removes the highlight from Column B and updates value after recalculation.

```
Sub recalculate_button()
 Dim Value1, Value2 As Integer
 Value1 = 50
 Value2 = 30
 Range("B1:B5000").Value = Value1 + Value2
End Sub

Sub Highlight_button()
 Range("B1:B5000").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```

My expectation is to update Column B without removing the highlights.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you please show us the code? Without it there is little to nothing that we can help you with.

Comment: If you change `Range("B1:B5000") = Value1 + Value2` to `Range("B1:B5000").Value = Value1 + Value2` ?

Comment: Thanks! Im new to VBA. Forgive me for blunders.

Comment: still the issue persist

Comment: Setting the value of a cell doesn't change the formatting. Do you have any conditional formatting on the cells?

Comment: No. The column B just gets highlighted when Highlight button is clicked.